# How to get Asp.net MVC route info inside referenced class library?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying get Route info from reference class library. can anyone suggest what would be the best way to get the required information.

Comment: Can you share some code to give us a better idea of what you're doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adopt any of the approach below:
1. Pass route info the class library method from mvc controller where you want to get it
2. add system.web reference dll in class library and try to fetch using System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"]

Note: second approach is not preferred one.

Comment: thanks for the tip, i will try your first solution.